How do I prep and paint this exterior door and trim in one day?
Does anyone have tips on how I might best paint this door and trim? I'm hoping to complete the project tomorrow but I'm struggling to remove the paint from the trim especially in the curved sections. I've watched videos of people using infrared paint strippers and specialty shaped scrapers but I don't have access to those tools.
The existing paint has some blistering and has failed in places. So far I've sanded the door with an orbital sander using 80 grit and removed the paint from the threshold using a trim sander. I added some wood filler to the cracks in the threshold. I'm wondering if I should add some wood filler to the cracks in the lower portion of the door?
I'm planning to use Zinsser Cover Stain Primer (oil based) on the threshold and any bare spots on the door. And then follow that with Benjamin Moore Regal Select. I'd be grateful for any pointers or tips. I'm wondering if I should take the door off the hinges or just try and carefully paint it in place? Thank you

A one-day paint job feels likely to fail more quickly than one you take more time over and use higher quality materials on. Given why you're doing this, are you sure that's what you want?

90% of a good paint job is in the prep work. If you shortchange the prepwork to get it done quickly, your shortchanging will be repaid with interest on how long it doesn't last.

I'm a little nervous about using the heat gun and inadvertently igniting dust particles I can't see behind the walls.

I guess my question is how important is it to fully remove the paint on the trim? I went to three different paint stores but was unable to find any of the curved scrapers that would allow me to effectively get in the trim.

Have you dealt with the long-standing damp problem?

Why do you need it done in one day?

You need primer on the whole door, not just bare spots.

And if you don’t remove it from the frame (hint: hinge pins), you won’t be able to effectively paint all the edges.

Power tools on a job this size?
80 grit sanding sponge to remove loose or flaking paint. 240 grit to finish.
Then prime and paint as per paint manufacturers instructions.
If you want to get fancy remove the lock hardware before and reinstall it afterwards.
It looks like the sill is worse for wear, an epoxy paint may help there, but only if the damp problem has been resolved.

I usually attack this kind of project with a sander and start with 80 grit and finish with 240 grit, to remove the old paint if it is cracky and pealing. If the old paint is in a good shape, then I just paint over it
However the molding is another question, and I usually give up and just replace it.
I do use turpentine to wash the surface and remove the grease.
